# Rewriting PHP script from mysqli to pdo code

Tags: php

I am rewriting my php code form mysqli to PDO, now I get a few error messages when I want to post my data.

I hope someone can help me im a starter with learning pdo :)

Over here a screenshot with the error messages

screenshot: https://gyazo.com/f4c6f6686014facb59d0fd40f1ebe522

```html
<body>
            <font color="black">
                <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    <table class="table-fill">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-left">Film:</th>
                                <th class="text-left">
                                    <input style="text" name="txtFilm">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Genre:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <select name="Genre">
       <option value="Actie">Actie</option>
                            <option value="Fantasie">Fantasie</option>
                            <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
       <option value="Avontuur">Avontuur</option>
       <option value="Komedie">Komedie</option>
                            <option value="Romantiek">Romantiek</option>
                            <option value="Historisch">Historisch</option>
      </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Film omschrijving:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <textarea style="width:100%;resize:none;height:200px;" type="text" name="txtFilmomschrijving"></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Datum van uitkomst:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <input type="date" name="uitkomstdate">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Datum uit bioscoop:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <input type="date" name="Biosdate">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Film draai dagen:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Maandag" name="draaidag[]">Maandag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Dinsdag" name="draaidag[]">Dinsdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Woensdag" name="draaidag[]">Woensdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Donderdag" name="draaidag[]">Donderdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Vrijdag" name="draaidag[]">Vrijdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Zaterdag" name="draaidag[]">Zaterdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Zondag" name="draaidag[]">Zondag
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Film tijd dagen:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="12uur" name="tijddagen[]">12:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="14uur" name="tijddagen[]">14:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="16uur" name="tijddagen[]">16:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="18uur" name="tijddagen[]">18:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="20uur" name="tijddagen[]">20:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="22uur" name="tijddagen[]">22:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="24uur" name="tijddagen[]">24:00
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Zaal:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <select name="zaal">
                        <option value="normaal">Normaal</option>
                                    <option value="groot">Groot</option>
      </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Film afbeelding:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <input type="file" name="filmafbeelding" id="filmafbeelding">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left"></td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                     <center><input type="submit" value="Film toevoegen" name="btnHuur"></center>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                           
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br>
                </form>


                <br>

                <?php
include ("loginDB.php");
if (isset($_POST['btnHuur'])) {
$filmimage =$_FILES["filmafbeelding"]["name"]; 
$filmimagemap = "images/";  
$filmimagedoel = $filmimagemap.$filmimage;  
$draaidagen = $_POST['draaidag'];
$draaidag=""; 
foreach($draaidagen as $draaidagcheck) 
{ 
$draaidag.= $draaidagcheck.","; 
} 
$tijddagen = $_POST['tijddagen'];
$tijddag=""; 
foreach($tijddagen as $tijddagcheck) 
{ 
$tijddag.= $tijddagcheck.","; 
} 
    //film moet in de map /bioscoop/banner/ of /bioscoop/images/ staan//

$uploadfilm = "INSERT INTO films (film, movieimage, genre, Filmomschrijving, Datumvanuitkomst, Datumuitbioscoop, Filmdraaidagen, Filmtijddragen, Zaal) VALUES ('".$_POST["txtFilm"]."','$filmimagedoel','".$_POST["Genre"]."','".$_POST["txtFilmomschrijving"]."','".$_POST["uitkomstdate"]."','".$_POST["BiosDate"]."','$draaidag','$tijddag','".$_POST["zaal"]."')";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$uploadfilm);
    echo "Film toegevoegt!";
}
                
?>
```

NOTE THIS IS MY OLD MYSQLI PHP CODE SCRIPT:

```html
   <center>
        <div class="gallery1">
            <h3>Film toevoegen</h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>

 <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <table class="table-fill">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">Film:</th>
                    <th class="text-left"><input style="text" name="txtFilm"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Genre:</td>
                    <td class="text-left"> <select name="Genre">
       <option value="Actie">Actie</option>
                            <option value="Fantasie">Fantasie</option>
                            <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
       <option value="Avontuur">Avontuur</option>
       <option value="Komedie">Komedie</option>
                            <option value="Romantiek">Romantiek</option>
                            <option value="Historisch">Historisch</option>
      </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Film omschrijving:</td>
                    <td class="text-left"><textarea style="width:100%;resize:none;height:200px;" type="text" name="txtFilmomschrijving"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Datum van uitkomst:</td>
                    <td class="text-left"><input type="date" name="uitkomstdate"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Datum uit bioscoop:</td>
                    <td class="text-left"><input type="date" name="Biosdate"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Film draai dagen:</td>
                    <td class="text-left"><input type="checkbox" value="Maandag" name="draaidag[]">Maandag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Dinsdag" name="draaidag[]">Dinsdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Woensdag" name="draaidag[]">Woensdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Donderdag" name="draaidag[]">Donderdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Vrijdag" name="draaidag[]">Vrijdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Zaterdag" name="draaidag[]">Zaterdag
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="Zondag" name="draaidag[]">Zondag</td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">Film tijd dagen:</td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="12uur" name="tijddagen[]">12:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="14uur" name="tijddagen[]">14:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="16uur" name="tijddagen[]">16:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="18uur" name="tijddagen[]">18:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="20uur" name="tijddagen[]">20:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="22uur" name="tijddagen[]">22:00
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="24uur" name="tijddagen[]">24:00
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Zaal:</td>
                    <td class="text-left"><select name="zaal">
                        <option value="normaal">Normaal</option>
                                    <option value="groot">Groot</option></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left">Film afbeelding:</td>
                    <td class="text-left"><input type="file" name="filmafbeelding" id="filmafbeelding"></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                                <td class="text-left"></td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                     <center><input type="submit" value="Film toevoegen" name="submit"></center>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
    </center>
    
     <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=fastmovierenessefrank",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
$sql = "INSERT INTO films (film, movieimage, genre, Filmomschrijving, Datumvanuitkomst, Datumuitbioscoop, Filmdraaidagen, Filmtijddragen, Zaal)
VALUES ('".$_POST["txtFilm"]."','$filmimagedoel','".$_POST["Genre"]."','".$_POST["txtFilmomschrijving"]."','".$_POST["uitkomstdate"]."','".$_POST["BiosDate"]."','$draaidag','$tijddag','".$_POST["zaal"]."')";
if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
echo "Film toegevoegt!";
}
else{
echo "Er is iets misgegaan...";
}

$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

Comment: While your moving to PDO, its really worth learning prepared statements as this will improve the quality of your code.

Comment: @NigelRen Ikr but i need to rewrite it for my job :P

Comment: @Frankieboy2K If this is for a company even more of a reason to use prepared statements. You never do the `$draaidagen = $_POST['draaidag'];` in the PDO version, nor the `$tijddagen = $_POST['tijddagen'];` those are PHP notices/errors, not PDO.

Comment: So how it will look likes if you rewrite it? can you show it as example please. @user3783243

Comment: @Frankieboy2K You need to do the same assignments as you did previously. `mysqli` vs `pdo` makes very little difference. The advantage to the two of them over `mysql_` is the prepared statements, which you aren't using. I guess the PDO has the advantage that you can use it with different DBs as well.

Comment: @user3783243I know right but I got only 4 errors what's the problem over here than

Comment: This code is not salvageable.

Comment: look into php pdo bindparam http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Just include PHP code as what you asking. Including HTML make this question messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the issues:

1. `$_POST["BiosDate"]` != `name="Biosdate"`
2. No `$draaidag =`
3. No `$filmimagedoel =`, this item also isn't present in the `PDO` HTML form.
4. No `$tijddag =`.

You aren't assigning in the PDO code like you did in the mysqli code. In additional the real benefit to using these drivers is there ability to use prepared statements and parameterized queries. I think this would be closer to what you want. You'll need to figure out what the `$filmimagedoel` is suppose to be:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $hostname='localhost';
    $username='root';
    $password='';
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=fastmovierenessefrank",$username,$password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
        $sql = "INSERT INTO films (film, movieimage, genre, Filmomschrijving, Datumvanuitkomst, Datumuitbioscoop, Filmdraaidagen, Filmtijddragen, Zaal)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $params = array($_POST["txtFilm"], $filmimagedoel, $_POST["Genre"], $_POST["txtFilmomschrijving"], $_POST["uitkomstdate"], $_POST["Biosdate"], implode(',', $_POST['draaidag']), implode(',', $_POST['tijddag']), $_POST["zaal"]);
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        if ($sth->execute($params)) {
            echo "Film toegevoegt!";
        } else{
            echo "Er is iets misgegaan...";
        }
        $dbh = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Additionally, storing delimited data in a DB is bad practice. You should only have one data value in a column.